# How to read latest info from client side using Spring on backend?

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

Lately I was doing tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

And I want to do something similar.
 
1. Client pushed button on web application
 
2. I start doing some heavy operation on server 
 
3. I want to inform client in text box how its going for example:
 
- Started calculating fields
 
- Calculated fields
 
- Starting rendering 
Etc.

How to achieve that realtime information is given to web application client while doing some operations? 
Something like console output, but sended to end user.

Comment: Have you considered using timer service in client side, asking server side about operation progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject [`SimpMessageSendingOperations`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageSendingOperations.html) into any of your services. You can use it to send arbitrary messages to destinations. You can use `convertAndSendToUser` if you have security configured, otherwise, you can use `convertAndSend`. Just make sure the client is subscribed to the destination you are sending messages to.

Comment: That solved my problem. 

Im sending info after each operation by method convertAndSend from  SimpMessageSendingOperations to a proper queue which client is connecting with. Thanks.